# How to populate list of data in UI using MySql and NodeJs

Tags: mysql, node.js

I am new to NodeJs and I have been tasked to replace the existing hard coded data with the data being pulled out from the MySql Database. The Data is displayed appropriately in UI when hard coded data is passed.

Below is the hard coded code which am trying to replace

```
router.route('/vehicles').get(function(req,res){
    var category = req.param("category");
    var term = req.param("term");
    var vehicles = [
        {id:1,name:"Test1",price:120,image:"image1",category:"Petrol"},
        {id:2,name:"Test2",price:100,image:"image2",category:"Diesel"},

    ]
    res.send(vehicles);
});
```

Here's the Code for retrieving from Mysql database

```
router.route('/Vehicles').get(function(req,res){
    var category = req.param("category");
    var term = req.param("term");
    var query = 'select * from cars where category=\''+category+'\'';
    var Vehicles = connection.query(
        query,
        function(err,result){
            if(err) {
                res.send({message: err});
                return;
            }else {
                res.send(result[0]);
            }
        }
    );
});
```

On replacing with the above Sql code am not able to see any data being populated in the UI. I have created the table and inserted some values into it. Still am not able to see any data.

Here's my connection.js

```
var mySql = require('mysql');

var connection = mySql.createConnection({
    host : "localhost",
    user : "root",
    password : "root", 
    database : "test_db"
});
connection.connect();
```

Any help would be really appreciated. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

try this.

db.js

```
 var mysql      = require('mysql');
 var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host     : 'localhost',
 user     : 'xxxx',
password : 'xxx@123',
database : 'xxxxx'
});

 var db = function() {

}

 db.getConnection = function () {
  return connection.connect();

 }
module.exports = db;
```

server.js

```
     var connection = require('./db');
     var db = connection.getConnection(); 
    router.route('/Vehicles').get(function(req,res){
    var category = req.param("category");
    var term = req.param("term");

     db.query(
     'select * from cars where category= ?',[category],
      function(err,result){
        if(err) 
            res.send({message: err});
            else 
            res.send(result[0]);
        });
   });
```

Comment: I tried the above code still am not able to see the data in the UI. Am really missing something silly here.

Comment: try to print on console and see,  weather u getting data or not